# How bad is it to change the DOM in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'm a noob react developer, and I'm currently building a MERN App.

My question to the community is, in my project I had to modify the DOM multiple times as shown below:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style = 'overflow: hidden';
```

I know that changing the DOM very often is not recommended in React.Js. So is it ok if I did it only to cut the body's scroll-bar?

Comment: 1: You can use `document.body` and 2: You can simply use CSS.  One of the main things JS can do is manipulate the DOM.  What would be wrong in changing the DOM?

Comment: I mean, people say is bad to change the DOM, because react has a virtual DOM, and one of the reasons where react.js was created, it's to not change the DOM, so, i was wondering, if i do it a bit in my project, would it be a bad practice or it is okey?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I don't know that much about react.js (or any JS frameworks, I don't use them).  Then I guess the answer given below by CertainPerformance would be right for you.  Remember, if it worked for you, then you can accept the answer (click the check mark next to it).

Answer (score 3):

In React, changing the DOM directly is *usually* bad because the state of the page should come *directly from the state in React*.

But React will render *inside* the body - the body can't be something returned by the JSX inside a React component, so doing

```
document.body.style = // ..
```

really is the only way to change the body's style.

The time you wouldn't want to do such a thing would be if the element being changed was being rendered by React, eg:

```
// some functional component
const clickHandler = () => {
  document.querySelector('.foo').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
};
return (
  <div className="foo" onClick={clickHandler}>foo</div>
);
```

because you could instead toggle some *state* inside the component which changes the returned JSX to include the different style.

That said, your approach of

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style = 'overflow: hidden';
```

should be reconsidered, if possible:

- Use `document.body` instead of `getElementsByTagName`
- Do you really have to set the style of the whole `<body>`? It would be more inline with React to set the style of an element React is rendering, if possible - and then you can use the method mentioned above, of using *state* and the returned JSX instead of using DOM methods.

Comment: Thank you for your comment dude

And, what i'm doing is to cut the scroll-bar of the body, so i can have only one scroll-bar for a modal window that should appear after clicking a button, the way i make appear the modal window it's with state, and for cutting the scroll-bar i'm using document.body

And i apologize for my poor english :/

Comment: What you're doing is plausible, but it would be more React-like to put the *whole page* inside React, so that you can then change the style by altering the state of the top container.

Comment: All right, i get it, thanks, you're the greatest !

Comment: In addition, manipulating the DOM is expensive, you might get into an infinite loop